# ng-map showing two maps instead of one

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ng-map

I am using [This](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps) map library to show map in my website.

My html code for map is following:

```
<ng-map center="{{center}}" zoom="10" default-style="false" id="map">
</ng-map>
```

In my controller

```
$scope.center = "Manchester, UK";
```

When i load page it shows two map instance in map section as bellow.
I tried to reload map after add value to center as follow

```
$timeout(function() {
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
});
```

But still it showing same.

[image]

Comment: try to provide a fiddle or plunkr that might help

Comment: i tried to create plunkr, its working fine in plunkr, but not working in my browser. i tried on many browser.

Comment: try simple html file that includes angular, ng-map, ... from cdn. If it wont work in your browser-- post all file here(should be quite small)